Metronidazole physicochemical characteristics
In literature it is not clear whether the drug metronidazole is acidic or basic. However the British pharmacopoeia indicates that an aqueous saturated solution of metronidazole has a pH of 5.8. This tells me that I should consider it as a weak acid but the according to the structure the drug has no acidic groups.
So my question is whether metronidazole basic or acidic?

They should be much more clear about it, but I'm pretty sure it's used as a salt - that's why pH would be lower than 7.
